# Monitoring the websocket data through browser developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, web, websocket, firebug

Is it possible to see/monitor the data exchange through developer tools of browsers , like chrome already has the developer tools > network > websocket,But it only displays the communication handshake but no data exchange unlike the xhr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chrome, when you go to the "Network" tab in the dev tools and then click on a WebSocket connection, you can view the exchanged data by switching from "Headers" to "Frames" in the displayed WebSocket data.

Comment: Chrome 54.0.2840.99 m does not have this option, what to do in 2016?

Comment: Current Chrome  (54.0.2840.100) still has this option, and this works for non-secure WebSocket. For anything using TLS, all you see is "Binary Frame (Opcode 2)" - see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=605262

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox developer tools do currently (version 41.0) not offer a way to inspect WebSocket connections. There's an [issue filed for it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=885508), though.

The same relates to Firebug. There´s also an [issue filed for it](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/6452).